# getting error during fake authentication(aircrack-ng)

Tags: wireless

I am getting some error when I am sending fake authentication using airplay-ng on Ubuntu 13.04. It shows mon0 is in different channel.

Can u suggest me any patch which solves this problem

I also don't know how to install the patch

Comment: Disable your network manager, use `iwconfig` to change `wl0`'s channel to the AP's channel.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the answer on this link below and I was able to fix it on my Ubuntu 13.04

[How can I solve "fixed channel -1" (mon0 is on channel -1) issue when using airodump-ng?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318583/how-can-i-solve-fixed-channel-1-mon0-is-on-channel-1-issue-when-using-airo)

Make sure to install ssl lib dev before compiling aircrack from source.

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Also you will need to remove the previous version of aircrack-ng from your system before you install the compiled version just to make sure there will be no conflict.

`sudo dpkg --purge remove aircrack-ng`

Peace!!